# Still usage without are or is and the -ing form, not related to adjective without a verb

Tags: grammar, ing

"People are still coming out the church."
or
"People still coming out of the church."

I've seen people using both, but I'm not sure if they are both correct? Can you use still + ing without any other verb? "She still crying." "He still eating.", "Games still coming out", etc.

Comment: My question was different because that one was about adjectives while this is about verbs using the -ing form.

Comment: No, the question is the same because you are asking about omitting a main verb.

Answer (score 1):

No. Colloquially saving on verbs is easily forgiven but in writing you're supposed to put the verb there: "*people **are/were** still coming out of the church*".

"*People still coming out of the church...*" would demand a completion such as, for instance, "*... were looking worried at the cloudy sky*".

Comment: Ha, I edited too long!

Comment: @Davo and Chiron. I marked this as a dupe by the _same OP_, same question.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand why. Isn't "coming out" a verb itself? Why is it not fine alone?

Comment: @Blueshell: yes but it's just a present participle, not a stand-alone conjugated verb - see [here](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/ing-forms/)

Answer (score 0):

> People are still coming out the church.

This is a sentence. **People (subject) are (verb)** *something*.

> People still coming out of the church.

This is not a proper sentence, but it can be part of one:

> People already in their cars saw nothing. People still coming out of the church saw a rainbow.

Now it is a sentence: **People (subject)** *some description* **saw (verb)**  *something*.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand why. Isn't "coming out" a verb itself? Why is it not fine alone?

Comment: *Come* is a verb. In this use, *coming* is an adjective, and *coming out of the church* is an [adjectival phrase](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&client=opera&hs=9jG&q=adjectival+phrase) used to describe the people; a verb is still needed.